# I am writing a small c program which does thread synchronization

Tags: c, multithreading

I am a student and i encountered a following task using multithreading in c, the problem is I am trying to protect shared variable cnt using P and V operataions. I am using semaphore to protect the shared variable, but it is giving me following errors:

```
correctcntn.c:15:10: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
 sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);
          ^
correctcntn.c:15:18: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant
 sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);
                  ^
correctcntn.c:15:21: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant
 sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);
```

Thank you in advance! Any help is appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include<semaphore.h>

int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,  void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
void *thread(void *vargp); 
volatile long cnt = 0;     
sem_t mutex;
sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);  
void P(sem_t *s)
{
    sem_wait(&s);
}
void V(sem_t *s)
{
    sem_post(&s);
}            
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    long niters;
    pthread_t tid1, tid2;
    niters = atoi(argv[1]);
    pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, thread, &niters);
    printf("THREAD 1 with tid= %ld CREATED \n", tid1);
    pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, thread, &niters);
    printf("THREAD 2 with tid= %ld CREATED \n", tid2);
    pthread_join(tid1, NULL);
    printf("THREAD 1 with tid= %ld TERMINATED \n", tid1);
    pthread_join(tid2, NULL);
    printf("THREAD 2 with tid= %ld TERMINATED \n", tid2);
    if (cnt != (2 * niters))
        printf("BOOM! cnt=%ld\n", cnt);
    else
        printf("OK cnt=%ld\n", cnt);
    exit(0);
}

void *thread(void *vargp) 
{                                         
    long i, niters = *((long *)vargp);            
    for (i = 0; i < niters; i++)
        P(&mutex);
    cnt++;
    V(&mutex);                                                    
    return NULL; 
}
```

Comment: You should be including `pthread.h` rather than declaring `pthread_create`.

Answer (score 1):

Statements to be executed like `sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);` must be in function bodies in C.

You should move that inside a function body -- for example, at the beginning of the `main()` function.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    long niters;
    pthread_t tid1, tid2;
    sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1); /* move to here */
    niters = atoi(argv[1]);
```